# Getting the selected JRE path from Open Office(Tools>Options>OpenOffice>Java) for different OS via java

Tags: java, operating-system, openoffice-calc, uno

I do not want to install Java or JRE in the project that creates my open office calc project heavy to execute and is difficult to run on any OS with jars attached. Hence, I want to know the way to extract the path of jre selected in Open Office in any OS where my OXT file is installed via java. I am using UNO package for it.

I have put jre in the project of open office calc, but is creating problems.

Answer (score 0):

This question was cross-posted to the OpenOffice forums, and I think the responses there have the answer: 
[[Solved] Getting the selected JRE path from Open Office](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=83545&p=387867#p387867).

Comment: Yes, it was posted by me there too.